# Problems with dotnet instalation

Tags: raspbian

I try to install .NET core in Raspberry OS (latest version). I follow this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/iot/deployment

But when i type 'dotnet --version' in prompt, returns me file or directory not exists.

I use "cd /home/pi/.dotnet" and type dotnet in prompt and returns me "command not found".

When in type ls in .dotnet folder returns me

```
dotnet LICENSE.txt sdk shared ThirdPartyNotices.txt
host packs sdk-manifests templates
```

That is, the file exists.

What i'm doing wrong?